# Purpose of maven-source-plugin and maven-javadoc-plugin?

Tags: maven-3, maven-javadoc-plugin, maven-source-plugin

I've been doing some research on the maven source and javadoc plugins, and I wanted to inquire a bit about the usage of each.

I understand conceptually how the plugins work, and what they do.

What I'm confused about, is why you would want to bundle sources or javadoc along with your artifact. Doesn't the javadoc get published when you do site:deploy? If I am creating a JAR library that will be used as a dependency of another project in eclipse, will attaching javadoc or sources enable me to see the javadoc in eclipse when using functions in that library, whereas if I fail to use the javadoc plugin, they won't be available?

What is "forked-path" and "jar-no-fork"? They seem to be relevant to this. Like I said I've done a lot of researching, I just can't tie it all together. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse and other tools know how to download source and javadoc artifacts and use them to show you doc and source of your dependencies.

Forked-path and jar-no-fork are just about not running out of memory.